# Is there a clever way to show that $\sin (\phi+1)<\frac12$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, golden-ratio

I noticed that $\phi+1\approx 1.000015\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right)$, where $\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}$, the [golden ratio](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GoldenRatio.html).

So I wonder, is there a clever way to show that $\sin (\phi+1)<\frac12$, without a calculator?

Using Maclaurin series, we have $\sin (\phi+1)<\sum\limits_{k=1}^7 (-1)^{k-1}\frac{(\phi+1)^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}$, which, in principle, could be shown to be less than $\frac12$ without a calculator. But is there a better way?

Comment: It may help any series-related investigations to note that $\phi+1$ is $\phi^2$.

Comment: The "clever way" would certainly essentially consist of showing that $\pi < \frac 65(\phi+1) = \frac{3+\sqrt 5}{5}$, or that $25\pi^2<30\pi-4$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen I think you mean $\pi < \frac 65(\phi+1) = \frac{9+3\sqrt 5}{5}$, and $25\pi^2<90\pi-27$.

Comment: Is $(\phi + 1) < \frac{30}{360} \times 2\pi$?

Comment: Showing that $\frac{6}{5} (\phi + 1)$ is greater than the well-known upper bound $\frac{355}{113}$ for $\pi$ would suffice. (See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil%C3%BC) But eliminating the radical gives us an equivalent inequality between $2$ integers.

Comment: $\frac{3(3+\sqrt 5)}{5} >3.1416$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comment by @Travis Willse:

$5\times 339^2>758^2$

$\sqrt5>\frac{758}{339}=\left(\frac{355}{113}\right)\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)-3$

$\phi+1=\frac{\sqrt5+3}{2}>\frac{5}{6}\left(\frac{355}{113}\right)>\frac{5}{6}\pi$ because [$\frac{355}{113}>\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mil%C3%BC)

$\pi>3>\phi+1$

$\therefore \sin (\phi+1)<\frac12$

Comment: Note that we even have: $\frac{3(3+\sqrt 5)}{5} >3.1416$

Comment: And moreover, $31416$ is divisible by $3$, reducing noticeably the amount of computation.

Comment: @RezaRajaei How would you show that $3.1416>\pi$ ?

Comment: It's very easy to show that $3.1416>\frac{355}{113}.$